# Best way to license developer environments

Tags: sharepoint-server, licensing, development-enviroment

I need to license several developer environments for SharePoint Server (virtual machine with SharePoint Server for each developer).

I can see the following variants (sorted from expensive to cheap):

- Visual Studio Enterprise with MSDN
- Visual Studio Professional with MSDN + SharePoint Server commercial license
- Visual Studio Professional with MSDN + MSDN Platforms
- MSDN Platforms + Visual Studio Professional standalone license
- MSDN Platforms + Visual Studio Community (free)

The first one is "recommended". The last ones are MUCH cheaper.

What is the best way to license SharePoint developer environment?

Comment: Licensing demands differ by team size and project complexity. My advice to you is to contact a local licensing partner or to be assigned one by Microsoft, to help you determine the best licensing package for your development team.

Comment: From SharePoint developer point of view, is there any difference? As I can see, any of the variants listed is suitable. May be, there are some more I do not know about?

Answer (score 1):

To select the license for SharePoint developer environment, it depends on what software is included with each Visual Studio subscription you want to use, what’s the use rights and benefits for Visual Studio Subscribers, what’s the size of your server and so on.

Check the articles to get more information about Visual Studio license:

[Microsoft Visual Studio Licensing](https://www.visualstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/Visual-Studio-2017-Licensing-Whitepaper-November-2017.pdf) and [Compare Visual Studio 2017](https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/compare/)

Comment: I know what software is included in each subscription, and how much does it cost. I am sure all the variants listed are suitable. May be, there are some more (the first one is very expensive, others are strange for devlopers)?

Answer (score 1):

Provided a particular subscription level covers the software you require, it makes no difference if you go with that level or above for your needs. If the request is simply "I need a development SharePoint Server", then get the cheapest option.